# Find limit of sequence in category of cones.

Tags: category-theory

Consider the sequence of posets $$[0] \to [1] \to [2] \to [3] \to...$$ where $[n]= \{0 \leq 1 \leq \dots \leq n \}$ where the maps $[n] \to [n+1]$ are inclusion maps. Find the limit and colimit of this sequence, viewed as a diagram over the poset category $\mathbb{N}$.

How can the sequence be viewed as a diagram? Indeed, a diagram of type $J$ in $C$ is a functor $D: J \to C$ from an index category $J$ to a category $C$. I think the index category here is simply the category with objects $\mathbb{N}$ and maps as inclusions and the category $C$ is the same. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about your definition of diagram.  The $C$ in your case is **Poset**, the category of partially ordered sets and monotonic functions.  Each $[n]$ is a partially ordered set.  The index category is the *specific* poset $\mathbb{N}$ with the usual ordering relation, i.e. $\leq$.  This can be viewed as a category whose objects are natural numbers, i.e. elements of $\mathbb{N}$ and for which there exists a (single) arrow $n \to m$ iff $n \leq m$.  This category is the $J$ in your definition of diagram.  You could describe the object part of the actual diagram as $D(n) = [n]$ with the obvious action on arrows.

Comment: Thank you so much, then I have understood it right. My conclusion is that both the cone and the cocone only has one object each and that the limit is the empty set and the colimit is the poset of natural numbers. Is this correct? Im not sure about the my statement that the cone and cocones having only one object each.

Comment: @Sodan A cone would be a poset $A$ and a collection of monotonic functions $f_n : A\to [n]$ such that $\iota_n\circ f_n = f_{n+1}$ where $\iota_n : [n] \to [n+1]$ is the inclusion you mentioned. Of course, the definition of $f_n$ is forced for all $n > 0$ once $f_0$ is provided, so we can think of a cone (in this case) as a poset $A$ and a monotonic function $A\to [0]$. It's clear that $[0]$ with id is the limit. In fact, for any diagram of shape $\mathbb{N}$ in any category whatsoever, $D(0)$ and id will be the limit. The colimit is indeed $(\mathbb{N},\leq)$. Proving this requires induction.